# react js : display items using map method

Tags: reactjs

i want to display submodule names also inside div
this is my api data

```
"predefined": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "mainModule": "bonding",
            "description": "some random description 2",
            
            "sub_module": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "subModuleName": "activity of bonding",
                    "completed": false
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "subModuleName": "self care",
                    "completed": false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "mainModule": "main module 1",
            "description": "some random description",
         
            "sub_module": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "subModuleName": "sub module 1",
                    "completed": false
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "subModuleName": "sub module 2",
                    "completed": false
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
```

this is my axios to fetch the data from api and set my state called items

```
   axios
      .get(
        "url",
        config
      )
      .then((res) => {
      
        this.setState({ items: res.data.predefined });
       

       
      });
  }
```

this is the jsx i have used to display my api here `personData.mainmodule` and `personData.description` works fine since submoule names are inside an arrray not rendering i cannot use it as  `{personData.sub_module[0].subModuleName}`

```
   {this.state.items.map((personData) => {
              return (
                <>
                
                  <div className="activity">
                   
                  
                        <h3>{personData.mainModule}</h3>
                      
                      
                        
                            <span>{personData.description}</span>
                       
                     
                          {this.state.item.map((personData) => {
                            return (
                              <>
                                {personData.sub_module.subModuleName}  //error
                              </>
                            );
                          })}
                        </div>
                       
                </>
              );
            })}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{
    personData.sub_module.map(item => {
        return (
            <>
                {item.subModuleName}
            </>
        );
    })
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use current `personData` variable to access `sub_module` properties. And then you use another `Array.map` to render it.

```
{
    personData.sub_module.map(item => {
        return (
            <>
                {item.subModuleName}
            </>
        );
    })
}
```

Comment: I edited your answer instead of mine, sorry :/

Comment: @DimitarVeljanovski it's ok :))) same result.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate `this.state.items` again to get `sub_module`. You can do like this

```
    {this.state.items.map((personData) => {
        return (
          <>
            <div className="activity">
              <h3>{personData.mainModule}</h3>

              <span>{personData.description}</span>

              {personData.sub_module.map((data) => {
                return <div>{data.subModuleName}</div>;
              })}
            </div>
          </>
        );
      })}
```

This way you can iterate `sub_module` properly.